# How to resolve invalid column error in Oracle Apex?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to add a plsql script that will update a event after "Apply Changes" button is pressed in a form. So I added a new "Dynamic Action" to click event of that button, set the action to "Execute PL/SQL CODE" and wrote the following script in "PL/SQL Code" section

```
BEGIN
UPDATE EVENT
SET START_DATE = :P53_START_DATE,
END_DATE = :P53_END_DATE,
START_TIME = :P53_START_TIME,
END_TIME = :P53_END_TIME,
DESCRIPTION = :P53_DESCRIPTION,
WHERE EVENT_ID = :P53_EVENT_ID;
END;
/
```

But I keep getting this error when I hit "Apply Changes"

[image]

Is there anything wrong in the way I am selection the values from the fields using "P53_....."?

[image]

How may I solve resolve this issue?

Comment: Hello Samman, you don't need the "/" at the end. That is to execute your pl/sql in a command line environment like sql workshop or sqlplus. In apex it is not needed. On a side note... If a user hits "apply" then "dynamic actions" is not the logical action. It would make much more sense to submit the page and put this code in a page process on submit.

Comment: Also I strongly suggest you use "TO_DATE(:P53_END_DATE, '<whatever format you are using>')" just to ensure the date is interpreted correctly. In apex a date is just a string so you need to tell the db what format the date is passed as... Not just for end date but for any date field you're using

Answer (score 0):

Your update statement references `:P53_NEW.EVENT_NAME` for the table column `START_DATE`. That cannot be right. Replace it with the correct variable.

Comment: had experimented a bit with my code before posting. I must have overlooked it. I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

there are several things wrong with this code:

```
BEGIN
UPDATE EVENT
SET START_DATE = :P53_START_DATE, << suggest using TO_DATE(:P53_START_DATE,'<your date format mask>') instead
END_DATE = :P53_END_DATE, << suggest using TO_DATE(:P53_END_DATE,'<your date format mask>') instead
START_TIME = :P53_START_TIME,
END_TIME = :P53_END_TIME,
DESCRIPTION = :P53_DESCRIPTION, << this comma makes statement fail
WHERE EVENT_ID = :P53_EVENT_ID; 
END;
/ << trailing slash not needed
```

But as I said in the comments, are you sure you need a dynamic action for this ? The "apex way" of doing anything on a page submit is to execute pl/sql code in page processes on submit. Dynamic actions are designed to be used if code needs to be executed without submitting the case. This is just a comment, it is unrelated to your actual question.

--Koen

Comment: I made changes to the code as you suggested but nothing happens. Neither the event gets updated nor an error gets displayed. I thought it must be because I didn't select p53_event_id in "items to Submit". But when I did that an error occurs which simply just says "Error" nothing else. I don't know what must I do?

Comment: I did previously tried using processes as you suggested. But I am using same from to insert and update entries. So I was confused on how can I bound to each process to to their respective form submission (create or update). May be you can help and also thanks for you input.

Comment: you do so by using "when button pressed" condition.

Comment: Please debug your code using the apex debugger. That shows what is happening (or not happening). You're the best placed to debug your own code. P53_EVENT_ID definitely must be in the "items to submit".

Comment: in reply to "how to bound process to respective form submission": 
There are multiple ways to handle this. You could create one process per button or use the "when button pressed" for each case. Or you could use the ```REQUEST``` parameter which will contain the button name on submit and do someting like
```IF :REQUEST = 'SAVE' THEN <save code> ELSIF :REQUEST = 'CREATE' THEN <insert code> END IF``` . Strongly suggest you spend some time looking at the sample apps and going through some basic videos so you get familiar with the basic apex concepts

Comment: thanks for your input. I drop my view table and started working with the event table itself as you suggested in my another post. One minor problem that I am having is that when event id field is set to hidden( event_id is generated in the database itself ), as error saying event.event_id cannot be null appears. But when I just disable the field without hidden it works just fine. I don't just want to disable it, I want it not included in the form. Any suggestions? Again thanks a lot.

Comment: Suggest you post this as a separate question - additional questions in a thread are hard to work with in Stack Overflow. This question is no longer related to the original question. If you do post a new question, make sure to provide enough information about how you created the form.